Error when running redpanda connect(Benthos) in multiple pods with NATS Jetstream as input
I am running a redpanda connect(Benthos) with NATS Jetstream as input and getting an error:
"Failed to connect to nats_jetstream: cannot create a queue subscription for a consumer without a deliver group."
But as per redpanda connect(Benthos) documentation there is no config field for NATS Jetstream input as deliver group.
How to solve this? Below is my input configuration of connect file:
input:
  label: orders_publisher
  nats_jetstream:
    urls: [nats://nats:4222]
    subject: awsloadtest
    stream: orders
    queue: testqueue
    durable: awsloadtest 
    ack_wait: 30s
    max_ack_pending: 1000
    deliver: all


Hey Ben, I left a comment in the other thread you started on GitHub to ask for details on how to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/redpanda-data/connect/discussions/2695. Otherwise, some help from the NATS community may be required.

Hi,
Thanks for the reply. I will provide steps to reproduce the issue in the GitHub thread.

Hey, I asked the same question in the NATS community, and it turned out to be a NATS problem more than a Benthos one. The issue was caused by using both the 'queue' and 'durable' fields simultaneously. Removing the durable field while running Benthos with NATS as input in multiple pods solved the issue.

The NATS community mentioned that the error message indicated I was trying to subscribe to a consumer using a queue group ('queue': testqueue in my configuration), which is only needed when subscribing to a push consumer. However, the consumer I was trying to use ('durable': awsloadtest in my config) was configured as a pull consumer.
Removing the field 'durable' solved the issue.
